# How to update data with multi condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with 5 columns like this table below:
[image]

I wanna fill the approval column based on conditions such as:

```
APPROVAL = "Y" IN CASE
  (1) CUSTOMER_NEW <> CUSTOMER (as in the case CUSTOMER = 12467)  
  (2) CUSTOMER_NEW = CUSTOMER AND SALE_SHORT_ID COLUMN HAS DIFFERENT VALUE (as in the case CUSTOMER = 13579)  
  (3) CUSTOMER_NEW = CUSTOMER AND SALE_SHORT_ID HAS THE SAME VALUE THEN MAX(LEN(SALE_ID) (as in the case CUSTOMER = 65465)
ELSE "N"
```

My result expected to like this table:
[image]

Thanks for your support.

Comment: Please take some time to format your question to make it readable. ALL CAPS on every site or forum MEANS SCREAMING! It's also very hard to read. Mixing up all caps and SQL queries makes the question unreadable. No one will bother answering an unreadable question

Comment: `SALE_SHORT_ID COLUMN HAS DIFFERENT VALUE` compared to what?

Comment: My bad. Really sorry about that.

Comment: In case (2) means: Same customer but has 2 sale_short_id

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about all your your conditions but this one could do it:

```sql
UPDATE a
SET approval =
    CASE WHEN
        a.customer <> a.customer_new OR
        a.customer = a.customer_new AND b.sale_short_eq = 0 OR
        a.customer = a.customer_new AND a.sale_id = b.max_len_sale_id
    THEN 'Y'
    ELSE 'N'
    END
FROM
    thetable a
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            customer,
            CASE WHEN MIN(sale_short_id) = MAX(sale_short_id) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS sale_short_eq,
            ( SELECT TOP 1 sale_id 
              FROM thetable
              WHERE customer = c.customer
              ORDER BY LEN(sale_id) DESC
            ) AS max_len_sale_id
        FROM thetable c
        GROUP BY customer
    ) b
        ON a.customer = b.customer
```

Note that the columns `b.sale_short_eq` and `b.max_len_sale_id` are returned by a sub-query joined to the main query.

Especially `SALE_SHORT_ID HAS THE SAME VALUE THEN MAX(LEN(SALE_ID)` is not clear. Did you mean that SALE_ID must be the same as the maximum length SALE_ID? Because SALE_SHORT_ID cannot be the same than any SALE_ID. And what happens if two different SALE_IDs have the same max length?

See: https://dbfiddle.uk/7Ct87-Mk

Comment: Thanks for ur help! SALE_ID may not be the same length; a customer may have many SALE_ID depends on their group; this fact lead to SALE_SHORT_ID may the same or different; because SALE_SHORT_ID has been generated from SALE_ID

Comment: CUSTOMER_NEW = CUSTOMER and SALE_SHORT_ID has the same value then should flag "Y" to the row has max(len(SHORT_ID)). In this case, max_len_sale_id is not a column (as in the case CUSTOMER = 65465)

Comment: `max_len_sale_id` from a sub-query. Your example shows that `SALE_ID` must be equal to the row with `max(len(SALE_ID))`, otherwise, if you take `SALE_SHORT_ID` both records 65465 would have `Y`. So, either your explanation is wrong or your example is wrong.